# Ad-hoc connection in MeeGo

Tags: wifi, meego, broadcom

I am new to MeeGo.Problem is do not know how to create a wireless ad-hoc network.

```
         Network controller is Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n.
```

According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless they have mentioned the brcmsmac driver to be used.

Now MeeGo system is only able to connect to an access point.

To make it into ad-hoc mode I issued

```
         user# iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
         Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06):
         SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
```

where the problem lies does it is with the adapter or with driver? I want to create a network of ad-hoc systems.